# Using the patch function to visualize a mesh

Tags: matlab, 3d, mesh

I'm trying to visualize a mesh using the "patch" function in matlab R2016b.

My mesh data is a simple sphere consisting of a faces matrix `512x3` and a vertices matrix `258x3` structured like in the following figure (but with 3 vertices per face):

[image]

When I'm visualizing the mesh with a single solid color with the following command:

```
patch('Faces', mesh.sharedVert, 'Vertices', mesh.vertices, ...
      'FaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250])
```

There are no problems:

[image]

However, when I try to visualize different a color per face or per vertex, I get the following result:

[image]

This is the script for the failed attempts:

```
patch('Faces', mesh.sharedVert, 'Vertices', mesh.vertices, ...
      'FaceVertexCData', colors)
```

My `colors` variable is either a column vector of `512x1` (for faces) or `258x1` for vertices (for now I'm using random numbers in it).
According to matlab's "patch" documentation, under the "FaceVertexCData" section, it should work in both cases, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Matlab staff](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/356600-patch-facevertexcdata-being-overwritten-by-facecolor#answer_282273), you must set the FaceColor property to be either 'flat' (if using per-face colors) or 'interp' (if using per-vertex colors), because the default value of [0 0 0] over-writes the per-face/vertex values.

It's interesting that they didn't bother adding that information to the man page.